# How can I prove the limit of this function using epsilon-delta?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{\frac{4}{7}\} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{7x-4}$. Using the epsilon-delta definition, show that $\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = \frac{1}{3}$. So, I know that I need to find $\delta$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta \implies |\frac{1}{7x-4}-\frac{1}{3}| < \epsilon$. This is what I have so far:
$$
|\frac{1}{7x-4}-\frac{1}{3}| < \epsilon \\
-\epsilon < \frac{1}{7x-4}-\frac{1}{3} < \epsilon \\
-\epsilon +\frac{1}{3} < \frac{1}{7x-4} < \epsilon +\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{\epsilon}+3 < 7x-4 < \frac{1}{\epsilon} + 3 \\
-\frac{1}{\epsilon}+7 < 7x < \frac{1}{\epsilon} + 7 \\
-\frac{1}{7\epsilon}+1 < x < \frac{1}{7\epsilon} + 1 \\
-\frac{1}{7\epsilon} < x-1 < \frac{1}{7\epsilon} \\
$$
This next part is where I got confused. So, I said pick $\delta=\min(-\frac{1}{\epsilon},\frac{1}{\epsilon})$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\epsilon$ needs to be greater than $0$.  $-\frac 1{7\epsilon} \lt x-1 \lt \frac 1{7\epsilon} \implies |x-1|\lt \frac 1{7\epsilon}$.  So why not choose $\delta = \frac 1{7\epsilon}$?

Comment: Oh ok, so could I do $\delta=\min(1,\frac{1}{7\epsilon})$? I thought you needed a min function because that's how I've seen everyone do it.

Comment: You would need a $\min$ function if you had to choose some specific value of $\delta$ in your procedure.  I don't see any place where you needed to assume $\delta=1$.

Comment: Ok, so then if I choose $\delta=\frac{1}{7\epsilon}$, I can just work backwards to show that $|\frac{1}{7x-4}-\frac{1}{3}| < \epsilon \implies \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{7x-4} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Exactomundo.  Just plug it in.

Comment: Thanks for working this through with me! I just needed some extra guidance.

Comment: You're very welcome.